# Add reference charts?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Is it possible to add charts that refer to a "base"chart? I have many different pages that need the same chart to display. Each time new data comes in i have to change all of them. So is it possible to just change a single chart and have the others change with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! You can!

You can *paste special - Microsoft drawing object*

Or, make the original chart and when you copy and paste it to the other sheets, you can hold  <kbd>Shift</kbd> when you paste it so it's referential.

I'm sure there's a more technical explanation, it's just early.